# Adjusting laser cut plan from 3 mm plywood to 4 mm plywood

Tags: inkscape, scale

I have a laser cut plan that fits 3mm plywood I want to fit it to 4mm.
How to do it in the fastest way in Inkscape without resize the entire plan?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following what you're asking. What does the thickness of plywood have to do with the size of the plan? Why would you need to resize it?

Comment: This question is unanswerable. It depends on the design, for example if you have box cut edges you need to now adjust each edge to be a 1mm deeper. How to do this depends on exact design. Second this isn't really a graphic design question.

Comment: Perhaps this question should be in arts and crafts.se

Comment: or woodworking stack exchange